# Is it possible to know the true RGB value of a Xamarin color?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Wanted to find out if I can retrieve the RGB value of a Xamarin color (not programatically)? The RGB value they give you is obviously not correct.

For instance, `Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red` is `R=1 B=0 G=0`

Does 1 simply translate to `255`. In which any color that has a 1, the corresponding value is `255`? If so, then I understand. If not, then is there a way I can get the RGB value of a given color, particular red for my case? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Color/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 means 255/255.

In the Red color case you have: R:255/255, G: 0/255 B: 0/255

So if you have a value let's say 0.35 in one of the color values you just have to multiply it by 255 and you will have corresponding base-255 color = 90.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. Thanks.